# Issues with Using MongoDB on docker

Tags: mongodb

(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to downgrade your mongodb to 4.2.1 and use mongo-express 0.54